# Want to post data to another website and retrieve result using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to post `1da07cs102` to http://results.vtu.ac.in/results.php. This site uses `rid` as a name in `form`. Using javascript, how can I fetch my result from the above site and get result and display in my website. Please help me.

I have used the following code but seems to be not working. Please help me out.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
    document.write("<form method='post' name='newresult' action='http://results.vtu.ac.in/results.php'>");
    document.write("<input type='hidden' name='rid' value='1da07cs102'>");
    document.newresult.submit();
//-->
</script>
```

Using this code, I am getting same page as that of http://results.vtu.ac.in/results.php instead of the result page after entering my University seat number `1da07cs102` Please tell me how to fetch result from main website and display the result in my website.

Comment: I think you need to learn some basics, or to give someone to do this for you. Only thing that you do in your code is adding some html to you page. Than you submit that form to *action* url and actually you only load that url. If that even works :)

Comment: Yeah that's what. I want to load the main page and post the input **1da07cs102** automatically and then fetch the result and display it in my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [CURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) in PHP (sorry, it is not JS, but it may be simpler without JS)

```
<?php

// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://results.vtu.ac.in/results.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'rid=1da07cs102&submit=SUBMIT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

echo curl_error($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Strauberry but sad thing is that curl, smtp and php sockets are not supported by byethost server space provider.

Comment: You're welcome! I agree with aSeptik, you will have a problem with cross browser constraints using JS. Why do you want to show your ID on your public website :-)? You can install php locally an run it on your computer privately. For this see XAMPP (http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) for example

Comment: @SRIKANTH KV: unless the host provide such kind of GET callback, without "curl, smtp and php sockets" how do you want to make a POST request?

Comment: I was using curl method till now. 2-3 back, they blocked "curl, smtp and php sockets". So i need to access and fetch the result using other methods. Hosted using wordpress by byethost. "curl, smtp and php sockets" are available for premium users itseems. I am not a premium user.

Comment: Maybe this is not blocked: http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/ Didn't try the solution

Comment: Thanks strauberry, but i did not understand how to manipulate it to work with my website things. If you can please mention the modified code, then it will help me a lot :)  Thank you in advance :)